# error when updating cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I cannot update cabal on windows seven. When running `cabal install cabal-install`, I get the following error:

```
Linking C:\Users\sberg\AppData\Local\Temp\Cabal-1.18.1.2-10956\Cabal-1.18.1.2\dist\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring Cabal-1.18.1.2...
setup.exe: does not exist
Failed to install Cabal-1.18.1.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-1.18.1.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
cabal-install-1.18.0.2 depends on Cabal-1.18.1.2 which failed to install.
```

I could not find any information on haskellwiki/cabal faq. Am I missing something? I am using the version 2013.2.0.0 of the haskell platform for windows.

Comment: Cabal installs newer versions to `%USER%/AppData/Roaming/cabal/bin`, do you have this in your `PATH` before the path pointing at the system installation?  I've also run into problems before where `cabal` for some reason can't delete the old cache, try deleting `%USER%/AppData/Roaming/cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/00-index.*` and running `cabal update` again.

Comment: @bheklilr I checked my PATH & tried deleting the cache, but it did not solve the update problem. My cabal.exe file is in the haskell platform repository, and not in the Roaming/cabal/bin directory. Is that a problem?

Comment: Have you tried `cabal install Cabal`?  The `cabal-install` package depends on the library `Cabal`, the API and the executable are split into separate packages so that someone can use the API without being tied to a particular executable.  Does that succeed?

Comment: @bheklilr I tried and it gave me the same error message, minus the last line. However I forgot to mention that I have installed eclipseFp which make use of the cabal API. I wonder if it has something to do with that.

Comment: I couldn't say, I've never tried out EclipseFp.  I think someone else will have to help out at this point, I've exhausted my experience of cabal problems on Windows =/

Comment: @bheklilr thanks for your help. I will dig around and come back when I have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround, which is to run the command `cabal install cabal-install` with MSYS.

I noticed however that with the newest cabal, I get a lot of `does not exist` errors when running `cabal install --only-dependencies` or `cabal configure` if you are not in a MSYS console.

**Edit** In my case it was caused by a local 64bits perl install. Reordering perl & the haskell platform in my path solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, tried to run it through MSYS but it did not work for me.

Solution for me was to modify the %PATH% environment variable to only keep the standard Windows directories and the Haskell ones.

I suppose the build tools found with R and Python were interferring in the build process.