# runhaskell setup configure [ installing]

Tags: haskell, runhaskell

When I try to configure the Cabal-1.18.1.3 package I get the error:

Configuring Cabal-1.18.1.3...
Setup: does not exist

My system is Windows 8 Pro x64, 2GB RAM, 1.7GHz dual core.\

tried:
I have tried writing Setup as Setup.hs

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a Cabal bug.

See: [error when updating cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553435/error-when-updating-cabal/22636320#22636320)

--> try using msys or cygwin.

I have submitted an issue:
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1741

Edit: It might be caused by a local 64bits perl install. Reordering perl & the haskell platform in your path could solve the issue.